# Error trying to upload files from one web to an API

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, laravel, post

I'm currently working on 2 different sites, the first is a web site where users can upload files, and the second its an API where the files are uploaded (this because the web site is very old and untouchable).

I'm using Laravel (6) to build the API, I have tested it with Postman and the files upload correctly, but when I try to integrate it with the web site, (build on a very old deprecated version of CakePHP ) doesn't work, it even doesn't reach the server (I was checking the Apache access log).

I have tried with AJaX, JQuery Post, and put the API URL on the action property of the form, but none of this methods works, anyone knows a proper way of achieve this?.

This is the form that I'm using:

```html
<form class="frm-upload form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadpictures" method="post" name="uploadpictures" >
    <div class="button small fileUpload white" data-original-title="" title=""> 
        <span> <i class="icon-cloud-upload"></i> Upload</span> 
        <input class="upload field-file" multiple="" name="images[]" placeholder="File" type="file">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the last JavaScript code that I have tried:

```js
$('#uploadpictures').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "https://api.something.com/file/uploadfromothersite",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
                if(data.check){
                    alert("success");
                } else{
                    alert("Fail");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm just getting a timeout error exception, please I need some help!

Comment: try to console log "this" in the console and check what's inside

Comment: Should it be http instead of https?

Answer (score 0):

let to add this in you ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                 }
            });
```

Comment: Im sending the info from Cake, not laravel, so its not a problem of CSFR TOKEN

Comment: sorry for it. my bad